# PHPStorm & PHPUnit - Unable to attach test reporter to test framework

Tags: phpunit, phpstorm

When running "Debug" in phpstorm on my project, for some reason it's started having this weird problem where phpstorm doesn't really pick up the test results, even though phpunit is not throwing an error.

Phpunit will generate a report in the phpstorm console that looks something like this:

```
[37;41m[2KFAILURES!
[0m[37;41m[2KTests: 3, Assertions: 6, Failures: 1.
[0m[2KGenerating code coverage report in Clover XML format ... done

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I'm guessing phpstorm can't interpret these results? It was working before and it would be nice to have full integration again.

Any help would be great

Comment: Disable colored output in your PHPUnit config

Answer (score 1):

It looks like phpunit colorizes its output. Could that be the problem? Make sure not to run it with `--colors`